# Getting Error while using WHMCS API

Tags: php, whmcs, laravel-5.6

While adding clients from WHMCS API we are getting an error as follows...{"result":"error","message":"You did not enter your first name"}

But our details get stored in the database and still we are getting the same error.Please find the code below..

```
Route::get('/addclient', function () {
Whmcs::AddClient([
    'clientid' =>'6',
    'firstname' => 'dfsfsd',
    'lastname' => 'Dsdfsoe',
    'email' => 'sfddfdsdfsdfsgdfg@gmail.com',
    'address1' => '123 Main Street',
    'city' => 'Anytown',
    'state' => 'State',
    'postcode' => '12345',
    'country' => 'US',
    'phonenumber' => '800-555-1234',
    'password2' => 'password',
    'responsetype' => 'json',

]);
return Whmcs::AddClient();
```

});

Comment: You have to create a variable for the function and return that.

Answer (score 1):

Try your code like this:

```
Route::get('/addclient', function () {
    $results = Whmcs::AddClient([
        'clientid' =>'6',
        'firstname' => 'dfsfsd',
        'lastname' => 'Dsdfsoe',
        'email' => 'sfddfdsdfsdfsgdfg@gmail.com',
        'address1' => '123 Main Street',
        'city' => 'Anytown',
        'state' => 'State',
        'postcode' => '12345',
        'country' => 'US',
        'phonenumber' => '800-555-1234',
        'password2' => 'password',
        'responsetype' => 'json',

    ]);
    return $results;
});
```

The line `return Whmcs::AddClient();` is telling your function to add client but without information, and that's why you get the error.

FYI, clientid not listed in [AddClient API function](https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/addclient/), so you can omit it.

Comment: glad it was helpful.